# Why does RabbitMQ's SimpleRpcServer use an explicit interface implementation for Dispose()?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, idisposable, explicit-interface

The class [RabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns.SimpleRpcServer](http://vega.frugalware.org/tmpgit/mono/mcs/class/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/messagepatterns/SimpleRpcServer.cs) implements IDisposable using an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).  The implementation is:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    Close();
}
```

That means that in order to call `Dispose()` on such a object, I first have to cast it to IDisposable.  Why is the Dispose method declared in this way?  Should I bother to call Dispose() on a SimpleRpcServer object?  I could forget it and simply call `Close()`, I'm just asking because FxCop gave me a warning about it and I don't think I've seen explicit interface implementations before.

Comment: If you use it in a `using` statement you shouldn't need to cast it. Looking at the code, it was not done for naming conflict reasons. So my guess is `Dispose` is not important on this type or they are encouraging you to use `using`.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation was present in some .NET classes. The confusion related to whether you needed to call `Close`, `Dispose`, or both, when really they all perform the same action.

An example of a class that implemented it this was is `RegistryKey`. In [.NET 3.5 and before](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey_methods%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it explicitly implemented the `IDisposable` interface. This encouraged you to either use it in a using or call the `Close` method.

In [.NET 4.x and beyond](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the `IDisposable` interface was implicitly implemented.

I believe `Stream` was implemented in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

`IDisposable` came relatively late to the .NET Framework 1.0, as can be seen from [this discusson from October 2000](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/02/11/371015.aspx), and particularly the following extract:

> First, we are discussing formalizing a design pattern that we already use
>   within the framework.  All of our resource classes already support a method
>   called Dispose().  It is a public method that you can call at any time that
>   will release the resources contained by the object.  Think of it kind of
>   like the c++ delete operator but it doesn't actually free the memory, it
>   just runs the destructor.  We are considering making this an interface to
>   help codify the design pattern and facilitate some language support as
>   described below.

I believe (*) this is why many .NET 1.0 classes expose a `Close` method and only implement `IDisposable` explicitly.  And I think this was considered to be a mistake, which is why in later versions of .NET it is more common to see `IDisposable` implemented implicitly.  For example, a public `Dispose` method was added to the `Stream` class in .NET 2.0.

(*) my supposition, I don't have any inside knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It could be to maintain a common verb if the framework is provided in multiple languages where `Dispose` might not mean anything

Or it could be done because `Dispose` might not make as much sense if there is also an `Open` method since `Close` is a common opposing verb to `Open`.

For example, the ADO `DbConnection` classes all do this:

```
connection.Open();
conncetion.Close();
```

Alternativly, it could be that `IDisposable` was implemented after the product was already shipped and had an existing `Close` method and to maintain backwards compatibility `Dispose` was hidden by explicit implementation which `Close` then calls:

e.g.

```
// version 1
public class Thing
{
    public void Close() { ... }
}

// version 2
public class Thing : IDisposable
{
    public void Close() { ... }
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { Close(); }
}
```